# Best way to maintain a blacklist while scraping data - C# .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, web-scraping

I am writing a scraper in C# that will collect ID numbers from html. It sends out asynchronous http requests (using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem) for the html and the callback method parses the ID #'s from the html.

Each ID must be checked against a blacklist before being appended to a text file. Currently, I'm running a query against an embedded SQLite db on every single request to check against the blacklist and, if it isn't present, I then write the ID # to a file.

My application is consuming up to 90% CPU and I imagine it's because of how many read/write operations are done with every asynchronous callback.

So, is there a more efficient way that I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly unlikely you're seeing this kind of CPU load because of the SQLite query. You're performing one query per HTTP request - and HTTP requests take *a lot longer* than accessing a database, even if SQLite performs a full table scan.

You should use a profiler and find out which part of your code takes a lot of CPU. Again, unless your SQLite query contains a (large) bunch of complicated JOINs, I'm pretty sure it's not the problem.

Comment: i found out vs2013 has a profiler built in so this will be great. thanks for helping me with my spare time hobby :)